# Face the nearest empty patch netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I want to move some fish to the edge of a lake. The lake´s name is mallor so i established the edge like

`set edge patches with [mallor = 1 and any? neighbors with [mallor = 0]]`

Then

I have :

`ask fish [face min-one-of edge[distance myself] fd 1`

However, im noticing that alot of my fish are going to the same spot. To stop this i wanted to use

`ask fish [face min-one-of edge[distance myself] with [not any? turtles] fd 1`

but its not working, and i dont know whats the correct order to solve it

How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primitive you're looking for is `turtles-here`, not `turtles`

Furthermore, you placed your `with` in the wrong location. It should come right after the patch-set to which it applies.

Sometimes you might need brackets when combining `with` with other primitives. I don't know exactly when and where but Netlogo always corrects me with an error warning after which I can fix it, so for this specifically it's not too big of a deal.

`ask fish [face min-one-of edge with [not any? turtles-here] [distance myself]  fd 1]`

Do keep in mind that your fish will be moving around while on the edge.

Comment: Hello!, sooo close, thanks. But I got a new error message: Expected an agentset here, rather than a list  or block.

Comment: Hmm, then you might need to add some brackets. `min-one-of` behaves quite oddly when combined with `with`. I always forget the brackets as well until the error message reminds me of them.

Comment: @bksnlow does it work with this updated code?

Comment: Another update. The `with` had to be moved forward. I made a quick testcode and this time it seems to work for me.

Comment: Good morning, sorry for the long wait. It Works! Thank you. Now, I want to understand why? the order of the procedures seems weird to me

Comment: In the code how I wrote it, you look for the nearest piece of edge without any fish on it. In the code how you wrote it, you just look for the nearest piece of edge. Then you try to check if there are any fish on that piece of edge. But since you already only have 1 patch instead of a patch-set, `with` does cannot apply to it

Comment: `ask fish [ face ( min-one-of ( edge with [not any? turtles-here] ) [distance myself] )  fd 1]`
If I put in brackets to more clearly show the order or operation, you can see that `edge with [not any? turtles-here]` can be seen as a single unit. Splitting that unit up would make no sense.

Comment: But the strange part is that the key report is [```distance myself```] and its outside the parenthesis. Now I understand why i got the error message though. Thanks again for the help and the patience.

Comment: @bksnlow Oh right, yeah Netlogo handles parentheses a bit weird. You have to put the primitives inside the parentheses together with the parameters for the primitive